# What is the probability an individual in my class is at most 26 given he drives a truck?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

[image]

I already calculated my population mean and standard deviation I just need figuring out my X value. please help if you can

Comment: Welcome to CV, Madison! CV treats homework questions a little differently than other kinds of questions. Two things you can do that will improve this question and potentially get more and better answers are (1) add the `[self-study]` tag (you can edit your questions by clicking the "edit" link in the lower left, and by explaining in more detail what work you have undertaken so far on the assignment. Read more about the [`[self-study]`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the question involves choosing at random an individual of your class.

You don't need to compute standard deviation or mean. You just need to count how many people in your class drive a truck and how many of those are at most 26. Dividing the latter by the former you get the probability that the individual is at most 26 given that he drives a truck.